# Rails render request.referer error missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

1. Rails 4.2.1

   2. Bootstrap 3
   3. Simple_form

I have a three page user edit, (profile, account, settings) system.

```
app/view/users
   _form.html.erb
   edit.html.erb
   edit_account.html.erb
   edit_profile.html.erb
   edit_settings.html.erb
   new.html.erb
   show.html.erb
```

I will post the `edit_profile.html.erb` some proprietary info will be removed.

`edit_profile.html.erb`

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit Profile") %>

<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><%= link_to 'Profile', "#profile", "aria-controls" => "profile", "role" => "tab", "data-toggle" => "tab" %></li>
    <li role="presentation"><%= link_to 'Bio', "#bio", "aria-controls" => "bio", "role" => "tab", "data-toggle" => "tab" %></li>
    <li role="presentation"><%= link_to 'My Websites', "#websites", "aria-controls" => "websites", "role" => "tab", "data-toggle" => "tab" %></li>
    <li role="presentation"><%= link_to 'Upload Photos', "#photos", "aria-controls" => "photos", "role" => "tab", "data-toggle" => "tab" %></li>
    <li role="presentation"><%= link_to 'Upload Videos', "#videos", "aria-controls" => "videos", "role" => "tab", "data-toggle" => "tab" %></li>
</ul>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <%= simple_form_for @user, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
                    <div class="form-inputs form-inline well">
                        <legend>Tell us about yourself!</legend>
                        <%= f.input :birthdate, as: :date, 
                            start_year: Date.today.year - 18,
                            end_year: Date.today.year - 100,
                            order: [:month, :day, :year],
                            :label=> 'Date of Birth',
                            :required => true %>
                        <br>            
                        <%= f.input :age_valid, 
                            :as => :boolean, 
                            :label => false,
                            :checked_value => true,
                            :unchecked_value => false,
                            :inline_label => 'I am 18 years of age or older.' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li><%= f.button :submit, 'Update Profile', :class=> "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
                <% end %>     
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <ul class="h6c">
                    <li>Q. How old do I need to be?</li>
                    <li>You need to be at least 18 years old.</li>
                </ul>   
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="bio">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="websites">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="photos">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="videos">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The `edit.html.erb` is exactly the same except it has code from all of the other three files combined. There is nothing different in it.

In `user.controller.rb`

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
    case params[:form]
      when "profile"
        render "edit_profile"
      when "account"
        render "edit_account"
      when "settings"
        render "edit_settings"
      else
        render :action => :edit
  end
end
```

Each of the above pages has 4 or more tabs on it. each tab containing a part of the user forms. In my nav (not the tabs on the individual pages) I have link_to like this.

```
<li><%= link_to 'My Profile', current_user %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Write' %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Upload Photos', edit_user_path(current_user, :form => "profile") %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Upload Videos', edit_user_path(current_user, :form => "profile") %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'Edit My Profile', edit_user_path(current_user, :form => "profile") %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'My Settings', edit_user_path(current_user, :form => "settings") %></li>
<li><%= link_to 'My Account', edit_user_path(current_user, :form => "account") %></li>
```

Then I have the update also in the `user.controller.rb`

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
  else
      render request.referer <---- this gives me template missing error.  
      **render "edit"** <---- this doesn't work either as it takes me to the wrong page
  end
```

end

If the user makes a mistake on one of the three pages it should render back to the referring form page with validation errors on it.

Address bar URLs. 
On profile edit page `http://localhost:3000/users/2/edit?form=profile`
On missing template page `http://localhost:3000/users/2`

Full error. 
    `Missing template http://localhost:3000/users/2/edit?form=profile with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "D:/Development/projects/#/app/views"`

Comment: You'll need to explicitly define which template it should render.  The request.referrer is the url that you came from - you may want to pass the current template in as a hidden variable on the form if you stick with this method.  A note - you wouldn't have to do this if you had separate controllers for each of the edit modes (profile_controller, account_controller, settings_controller).  Putting the conditional logic in the controller action doesn't get you much - instead you'd put the logic in routes and the controller actions stay simple.

Comment: I'm new to rails though not completely incompetent to it. What you suggest sounds great but I don't know how to implement either suggestion. Since all of the profile, account, and settings are tied to the user database. Everything is stored in the user table.

Comment: Got it now. I figured out how to make the other controllers.

Comment: `render request.referer` should be `redirect_to request.referer`

Comment: Render works to but I ended up just separating the user controller into 3 parts. It's working great now. I'll work on creating a helper or something to DRY the code out later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note - you wouldn't have to do this if you had separate controllers for each of the edit modes (profile_controller, account_controller, settings_controller). Putting the conditional logic in the controller action doesn't get you much - instead you'd put the logic in routes and the controller actions stay simple.

So I did this by creating the three separate controllers

`rails g controller account`
`rails g controller setting`
`rails g controller profile`

In the routes.rb I added.

```
resources :profile, :only => [:edit, :update] 
resources :account, :only => [:edit, :update]
resources :settings, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

Then just copied the edit and update methods from the user controller to these new controllers. Created the `edit.html.erb` in each view directory and all is working the way it should.

Comment: That's great.  It's also very easy to make a single controller and subclass it (put the views in a similarly named subdirectory) to dry up the code.  If all your views are named .../edit.html.erb, you will probably have mostly empty subclassed controllers.